# Correct syntax for SSRS Nested IIf needed

Tags: service, reporting-services, nested, reporting, iif

I have the following expression. Can somebody tell me why it is printing 0.

```
=IIF(Parameters!StartMonth.Value <= 1 And Parameters!EndMonth.Value >= 1, ReportItems!txtTotal1.Value, 
IIF(Parameters!StartMonth.Value <= 2 And Parameters!EndMonth.Value >= 2, ReportItems!txtTotal2.Value,
IIF(Parameters!StartMonth.Value <= 3 And Parameters!EndMonth.Value >= 3, ReportItems!txtTotal3.Value, 0)))
```

Thanks

Comment: If I just put the first line it get the desired value. But as soon as I add another line, it shows 0. I tried this with the SWITCH statement too and same.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like if `Parameters!StartMonth.Value` is > 3, your statement will return 0.

Comment: I thought so, so I tried changing that 0 to 123123123 and still it prints 0 and not 123123123.

Comment: what are your start and end month values?

Comment: My start and end month values range from 1 to 12. Basically I am using that start month and end month logic to hide columns from my report dynamically. I am putting this formula in the Totals column.